# Scheduled task giving last run result 0x80041324

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I've got a scheduled task set up in my Windows 7 machine which is meant to run a BAT file when I'm not around, i.e. the machine has been idle for 15 minutes.

Does anyone know how to track down the cause of the error code ?

Checked on MSDN and it says ...

> SCHED_E_TASK_ATTEMPTED
>   0x80041324
>   The Task Scheduler service attempted to run the task, but the task did not run due to one of the constraints in the task definition.

And to confuse me even further, I've just noticed it has run while I'm at the machine with last result (0x0)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look on your task properties, there is the `Conditions` tab. Any of these conditions could stop the task. For instance, if you have `Start the Task only if running on AC Power` and `Stop task if the computer switches to battery power`, and you unplugged your laptop, that would cause this exit condition.

Same goes from `Start only if only has been idle for ...` and `Stop if no longer idle`.

That's just an example of anything on that tab which could cause it not to run or stop running prematurely.